# How to install lightsquid on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: server, apache2, squid

I installed lightsquid using `apt-get install lightsquid` and I followed this tutorial: https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=squid&f=7

Except in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/lightsquid.conf` before the `<Location...` I have line `Alias /lightsquid/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/lightsquid/`. It doesn't matter if I keep it there or if I delete it, I get the same result: When I try to connect to my server ip by typing `<server ip>/lightsquid/` to address line from client pc on lan using firefox I get what looks like source code of the page that should appear. It looks like php, but it might be perl (since I don't know perl). Anyway when I click right mouse button on it and choose Show source code, it shows the same thing :-).

What do I do to make it show the "real" page and not the source code (maybe it is not source code but some sort of script?)?

Edit: It actually shows the file `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/lightsquid/index.cgi`

E2: I have perl and apache2 installed on my server, I assume they installed automatically with lightsquid as dependencies. The server has routing and firewall by shorewall, dhcp, cache dns, squid proxy.

E3:`/etc/apache2/conf-available/lightsquid.conf`
https://i.imgsafe.org/ae59aa9d3f.png `/etc/lightsquid/lightsquid.cfg`
https://i.imgsafe.org/ae59cb62dc.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/ae59e20a05.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/ae59f94ddb.png
https://i.imgsafe.org/ae5a063a92.png

E4: `a2query -m cgid` cgid (enabled by site administrator)

E5: `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf` http://paste.ubuntu.com/23424551/

E6: In `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` is only directory lightsquid with this content: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23424573/

BTW I can see correct apache2 ubuntu default page by typing server ip into address bar of firefox https://i.imgsafe.org/c43a938efe.png

E7: `ls -la /var/www/html/` `ls -la/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` `ls -la /usr/lib/cgi-bin/lightsquid/` https://i.imgsafe.org/0395a7b6d6.png. What permissions should I check? I added this in png because I think you can see permissions there.

E8: https://i.imgsafe.org/172112069d.png https://i.imgsafe.org/17212262ee.png https://i.imgsafe.org/17213444dd.png https://i.imgsafe.org/1721419631.png https://i.imgsafe.org/17215b5c49.png https://i.imgsafe.org/1721678f62.png

E9: This is what I have in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/lightsquid.conf` http://paste.ubuntu.com/23449739/ and this is what I have in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/lightsquid.conf` http://paste.ubuntu.com/23449744/ It is identical. When I run `sudo a2enconf lightsquid` it says `Conf lightsquid already enabled`

E10: This is from `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log -f` when I reload page in browser: https://i.imgsafe.org/abb494716b.png

Comment: I added those two which I edited from their original state. If I should post more config files tell me please which ones.

Comment: cgid (enabled by site administrator)

Comment: could you elaborate? dont understand what to look for in what conf files or what is htaccess. thanks

Comment: `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/serve-cgi-bin.conf` http://paste.ubuntu.com/23424551/
In `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/` is only directory `lightsquid` with this content: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23424573/ I can see correct apache2 ubuntu default page by typing server ip into address bar of firefox https://i.imgsafe.org/c43a938efe.png

Comment: `serve-cgi-bin.conf` seems good as default (same as mine). `.htaccess` are hidden files so could check with `ls -la /var/www/html/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/lightsquid/` . apache2 default index is html (`index.html`), so it can't prove cgi is working, it just confirm that apache2 is running which is same case of getting that perl file from lightsquid in browser, I have default setup of apache2 and it's working fine. Permissions also have a hand here, if you can verify them.

Comment: all seem good, all scripts and folders excutable flag is on. basic question, have you restarted apache2 service after setup of lightsquid.

Comment: after `a2enconf lightsquid` I restarted apache2 by `systemctl restart apache2`. I proceeded using this manual https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=squid&f=7

Comment: Let's split the problem and see if cgi default folder working. (1) install some perl examples  `sudo apt install libfcgi-perl` , (2) then copy simple example to cgi-bin folder `sudo cp /usr/share/doc/libfcgi-perl/examples/echo.pl /usr/lib/cgi-bin/; sudo chmod +x /usr/lib/cgi-bin/echo.pl` (3) check it from the browser `http://localhost/cgi-bin/echo.pl`

Comment: http://i.imgsafe.org/063e824894.png (I am on the lan, server is text based `ubuntu 16.04 server`)

Comment: nice, it's working . make copy of it  in same folder and name it `echo.cgi` , and copy both to lightsquid folder , then test the three in the browser

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/172112069d.png https://i.imgsafe.org/17212262ee.png https://i.imgsafe.org/17213444dd.png https://i.imgsafe.org/1721419631.png https://i.imgsafe.org/17215b5c49.png https://i.imgsafe.org/1721678f62.png

Comment: Wait...we may be missed something, the file `/etc/apache2/conf-available/lightsquid.conf` existance does not mean it is enabled.  You should have a link to it from `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/lightsquid.conf`. Could you confirm that you have it, otherwise run this again `sudo a2enconf lightsquid; sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: How do I confirm it? This is what I have in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/lightsquid.conf` http://paste.ubuntu.com/23449739/ and this is what I have in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/lightsquid.conf` http://paste.ubuntu.com/23449744/ It is identical. When I run `sudo a2enconf lightsquid` it says `Conf lightsquid already enabled`

Comment: There is a typo mistake in location, this is the correct one `<Location "/lightsquid/">` , do you see it?

Comment: I changed it in both `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/lightsquid.conf` and `/etc/apache2/conf-available/lightsquid.conf`. When I try to connect in browser it says Internal server error http://i.imgsafe.org/30b108bfcc.png

Comment: Could you post the contents of `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/lightsquid.conf` after correcting path.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23455412/

Comment: Does `http://localhost/cgi-bin/lightsquid/` work for you?

Comment: same internal error

Comment: Now it says Forbidden You don't have permisson to access /lightsquid/ on this server.

Comment: I think the problem is in `/etc/apache2/conf-enabled/lightsquid.conf`, something we couldn't notice in syntax or hidden characters (from copy/paste). Try writing new lightsquid.conf file from scratch (avoid copy/paste).

Comment: Hi. Deleted old and wrote new lightsquid.conf file. Didn't help. Still `403 Forbidden`. I am now (I mean the desktop PC which I am using to connect to server) on different subnet - same as the WAN interface, but It should'n have impact. (I deleted line `Require local` and changed line `Require ip` to appropriate ip of pc I am connecting from (munin works with that config in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/munin.conf`))

Comment: This is from `tail /var/log/apache2/error.log -f` when I reload page in browser: https://i.imgsafe.org/abb494716b.png

Comment: It could be a default index issue (that does not accept index.cgi). Try `http://localhost/cgi-bin/lightsquid/index.cgi` and `http://localhost/lightsquid/index.cgi` . Those echo.pl & echo.cgi should work now try them too.

Comment: `http://ip_adresa/lightsquid/echo.cgi` works `http://ip_adresa/lightsquid/echo.pl` works `http://ip_adresa/lightsquid/index.cgi` works `http://ip_adresa/cgi-bin/lightsquid/index.cgi` works `http://ip_adresa/lightsquid/` doesn't work. BTW I lost track, why the echo.pl, echo.cgi and index.cgi work now pls?

Comment: When we changed the `<Location "/lightsquid/">` remember, the error message changed too, it means that was an issue and got fixed, but you were having another issue which I couldn't figure out till you mention that log message. the 2nd issue seems: apache2 look for `index` file `*.html`,`*.htm`..  but not `*.cgi` and this confirmed with your last results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First issue was typo mistake in `Location` declaration in `lightsquid.conf`.

   Wrong: `<Location "lightsquid/">` 
   Correct: `<Location "/lightsquid/">` with leading `/`
2. Second issue which I believed that mod-autoindex is enabled by default, but it does not seems the case for you or it's configuration modified (so it doesn't look for `index.cgi`).

   Other way to fix it without looking much around:

   - Add add new directory index declaration to `lightsquid.conf`

     ```
     ~$ more lightsquid.conf 
     Alias   /lightsquid/    /usr/lib/cgi-bin/lightsquid/

     <Location "/lightsquid/">
             Options +ExecCGI
             AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
             DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.pl
             Require local
     </Location>
     ```

Comment: Adding +Indexis does this http://i.imgsafe.org/aef06ab62d.png add new directory results in 403 Forbidden

Comment: @sedlv, Excuse me, i luck the knowledge in this area, but it seems `Directory` is an old directive that was replaced by `Location`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your endless patience and guidance!

Comment: @sedlv, you are welcome, I always learn things with such problems. I hope same for you as we have reviewed many aspects.